# What are these plants? Please help identify

Tags: bulbs, lily, gladiolus

I bought Gladiolus (sword lily) bulbs from an e-commerce site. But the plants which have grown from the bulbs I received do not seem to be Gladiolus. I would appreciate any help in identifying what these plants actually are. The leaves are long grass-like but smooth and somewhat waxy, and the flowers are white as shown in the pictures.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it from a reddit answer. The plants I received are actually [white rain lily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zephyranthes_candida) rather than sword lily which I ordered.

Comment: That would have been my first guess; native pink ones are somewhat common here . They bloom fast but then fade fast . More a novelty than a flower for a bed.

Answer (score 1):

Having difficulty recognising this - it might be one of the *Tritonia* - there is one called *Tritonia gladiolaris* with a synonym name of Gladiolus lineatus, which might explain why you haven't got the true *Gladioli* you expected, but the foliage looks a bit too narrow to definitely be that. Some images here  https://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/tritonia_gladiolaris.htm.  When you ordered, was there a Latin or botanical name for the bulbs?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Bamboo. But the leaves of the Tritonia gladiolaris in your link appears flat, blade-like. However, my plants have nearly cylindrical long leaves, which are also somewhat waxy. Unfortunately, no Latin name was there in the e-commerce page. It was only mentioned as Gladiolus and sword lily.

Comment: Well how odd - I'm not sure where you are, but rain lilies usually bud in August, so I wouldn't expect it to be in flower now in June..... it definitely  does look like Zephyranthes though, but I did not consider it because its June, not late summer...my oversight, given I don't know where you are